# converting html entity to utf-8 character

Tags: xml, grails, utf-8

I am having this problems in grails where I am writing a string from the database into an xml file using StreamingMarkUpBuilder. The xml file displays the string as htmlentities `&#x30b3 &#x30d4 &#x30fc`, how can I convert them to be printed as コピー?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this, I used OutputStreamWriter instead of FileWriter to enfored encoding to UTF-8

Comment: FileWriter (and FileReader) is very badly designed because it does not allow specifying a charset (which is usually better than relying on the platform default encoding). BTW, you might have had more luck getting an answer here if you'd shown the relevant code.